# change the text in the <h2> without change the span the same h2 tag

Tags: jquery, html

I want to change the text without change the span.
I tried this one the text is changed but the span was removed.

```
 <div class="c1"> <h2> "here" <span class="span1">X</span></h2></div>
```

is there any way to change the text without any change in the span content using jQuery.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/CanvasCode/y6p6xzfx/

```
$(function () {
    $span = $('h2').find('span')
    $('h2').text("Hello");
    $('h2').append($span);
});
```

Take a copy of your span, update the h2 text and then append the span back to your h2 tag.

---

Forgot to filter by the `c1` div class. here is the updated code

jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/CanvasCode/y6p6xzfx/1/

```
$(function () {
    $div = $('.c1');
    $h2 = $div.find('h2');
    $span = $h2.find('span')
    $h2.text("Hello");
    $h2.append($span);
});
```

Also you don't need to store all of the elements. I was just doing this to make the code clearer to read and understand.

Answer (score 3):

Update the `nodeValue` of first `textNode`.

1. **[`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)** -  get the dom object
2. **[`firstChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/firstChild)** - get the firstNode , in this case we can get the textNode
3. **[`nodeValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeValue)** - updating the textNode content

```js
document.querySelector('.c1 h2').firstChild.nodeValue = 'hi'
```

```html
<div class="c1">
  <h2>here<span class="span1">X</span></h2>
</div>
```

**UPDATE :** Or in jQuery use **[`contents()`](https://api.jquery.com/contents/)** and **[`replaceWith()`](https://api.jquery.com/replacewith/)**

```js
$('.c1 h2').contents().first().replaceWith('hi');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="c1">
  <h2>here<span class="span1">X</span></h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could acheive this by appending the `span` to `h2` element again:

```
var $span = $("div.c1 span.span1");
$("div.c1 h2").text("New Text");
$("div.c1 h2").append($span);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6e8gw7d2/10/

Answer (score -3):

Solution : $('.span1').text('ABC');

Comment: The question was not about the span content.